# trouble with header in CSV parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, header

I'm trying currently trying to learn how to use CSV and for all intents and purposes my code should work (mostly because I'm directly following a tutorial walkthrough). However, I keep getting an error message that my syntax is wrong. I'm wondering if it is something with ruby 1.8 on my mac terminal, or a gem I have to install. Basically it is saying my `header: true` is the wrong syntax. Here's my code and the subsequent error.

```
require "csv"
puts "EventManager initialized."

contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", headers: true, :header_converters :symbol
contents.each do |row|
  name = row[:first_name]
  puts name
end
```

However, every time I run it I get this error.

`lib/event_manager.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
...event_attendees.csv", headers: , :header_converters :symbol`

Anyone have a clue as to whats going on or what I should do/

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you're passing in the hash param to open. You need to be consistent when passing in the hash.

Try:

```
contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol
```

or (old style)

```
contents = CSV.open "event_attendees.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol
```